# Can I connect with WebSocket in an Android app?

Tags: android, html, websocket

I have an Android app and I want to send a text from the Android application to the webpage using HTML5 `WebSocket`.

Is this possible and if so how?

Comment: way too vague of a question. You need to be more specific about what you are trying to solve and what problem you are running into.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple google search for 'android websockets' turned up [this](http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2011/03/websockets-on-android.html).  He is referring to a GitHub project called [websocket-android-phonegap](https://github.com/anismiles/websocket-android-phonegap/tree/master/src/com/strumsoft/websocket/phonegap).

Comment: i saw this one before and i thought its only works for phonegap but if you did little modification you could use it in ur app

Answer (score 13):

I'm aware of 2 libs for Android supporting WebSockets from native apps

http://code.google.com/p/weberknecht

https://github.com/tavendo/AutobahnAndroid

Autobahn supports RFC6455 (the final WS spec), integrates well with UI and service apps and support RPC and PubSub over WebSockets.

Disclaimer: I am the author of Autobahn.

Comment: Weberknecht seems to have moved to GitHub:
https://github.com/pelotoncycle/weberknecht

Answer (score 0):

Answer is Yes, it is possible to send a text from app to a web page.
WebSocket works on the very principle of server and client over TCP/IP. Just a wrapper created over the TCP/IP layer and built a new data format which is defined by IETF. Details of the data format is available at  -
[https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455][1]

Server accepts websocket connection if requested in correct format. Client here is the web application in which javascript objects are defined solely for this purpose in HTML5.

Easy to use APIs:

Client side programming of the websockets are very easy with new APIs and objects defined.

APIs(events) available for the developer: onopen, onclose, onmessage. All these functions should be defined by the developers java script file.

onopen:  The function is called when the server accepts the connections succesfully

onclose: The function is called when the socket connection is closed

onmessage: The function is called when the data is received from the server.

send : the function is not event based but should be triggered when the client has the information to share with the server.